# Creating lists where each element is of length i

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, unique, list-comprehension

I am trying to make lists where each elements is of list `i` however with my current code below i get a bad result.

```
from itertools import combinations
x = 'ABCDABC'
y = [''.join(l) for i in range(len(x)) for l in combinations(x, i+1)]
z = []
for i in y:
    if i in x:
        z.append(i)

w = sorted(list(set(z)))

def Sorting(lst):
    lst.sort(key=len)
    return lst

final = 0

for i in range(len(z)):
    c = []
    for j in z:
        if len(j) == i:
            c.append(j)
    print(c)
```

result:

```
[]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C']
['AB', 'AB', 'BC', 'BC', 'CD', 'DA', 'AB', 'BC']
['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'BCD', 'CDA', 'DAB', 'ABC']
['ABCD', 'BCDA', 'CDAB', 'DABC']
['ABCDA', 'BCDAB', 'CDABC']
['ABCDAB', 'BCDABC']
['ABCDABC']
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

where it should be just:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C']
['AB', 'AB', 'BC', 'BC', 'CD', 'DA', 'AB', 'BC']
['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'BCD', 'CDA', 'DAB', 'ABC']
['ABCD', 'BCDA', 'CDAB', 'DABC']
['ABCDA', 'BCDAB', 'CDABC']
['ABCDAB', 'BCDABC']
['ABCDABC']
```

so that i can further manipulate

Answer (score 0):

to use only your code:

```
max_len = max(map(len, z))
for i in range(1, max_len + 1):
    c = []
    for j in z:
        if len(j) == i:
            c.append(j)
    print(c)
```

output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C']
['AB', 'AB', 'BC', 'BC', 'CD', 'DA', 'AB', 'BC']
['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'BCD', 'CDA', 'DAB', 'ABC']
['ABCD', 'BCDA', 'CDAB', 'DABC']
['ABCDA', 'BCDAB', 'CDABC']
['ABCDAB', 'BCDABC']
['ABCDABC']
```

---

to get your expected output you could use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for s in z:
    d[len(s)].append(s)
c = list(d.values())
c
```

output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['AB', 'AB', 'BC', 'BC', 'CD', 'DA', 'AB', 'BC'],
 ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'BCD', 'CDA', 'DAB', 'ABC'],
 ['ABCD', 'BCDA', 'CDAB', 'DABC'],
 ['ABCDA', 'BCDAB', 'CDABC'],
 ['ABCDAB', 'BCDABC'],
 ['ABCDABC']]
```

you are creating a dictionary where the key is the length of your current string and each value is a list with all the strings of the same length, to get the expected output you are only getting the dict values